# Django join two foreign keys in one table to another

Tags: mysql, django, django-models, left-join

I have two foreign keys that I need to join both fields simultaneously in a join. When I do my select_related like this:

```
.select_related('key1', 'key2')
```

It only does the join on one of the keys not both of them. I have them both declared as foreign keys and related_names equal to '+' and primary_key=True in the model.

Models from models.py:

```
class table1(models.Model):
    key1 = models.ForeignKey('table2', db_column='key1', max_length=6, related_name='+', primary_key=True) 
    key2 = models.ForeignKey('table2', db_column='key2', max_length=4, related_name='+', primary_key=True) 

class table2(models.Model):
    key1 = models.Charfield(db_column='key1', max_length=6, related_name='+', primary_key=True) 
    key2 = models.Charfield(db_column='key2', max_length=4, related_name='+', primary_key=True)
```

The error that is happening:

```
[table1] INNER JOIN [table2] ON ( [table1].[key1] = [table2 [key2] ) INNER JOIN [table2] T3 ON ( [table1].[key2] =T3.[key2] )
```

When it should be key1=key1 and key2=key2.

Comment: Please show your models (or simplified models that reproduce the problem).

Comment: I added more explanation. Hopefully this helps clarify the issue.

Comment: I don't think this is possible, because Django [doesn't support multiple column primary keys](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/373).